# Add hyperlink to AnchoredText

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made a diagram with matplotlib and added AnchoredText for labeling. I want to add hyperlinks to these labels, but not in a way that the whole label is a hyperlink - say, only a certain word of the label.

I know that I can use the **url** parameter in AnchoredText, but this is what makes the whole label a hyperlink, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText, AnnotationBbox, TextArea

fig_width = 16
fig_height = 9

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height))

fig.add_axes(
    (0, 0, 1, 1),
    alpha=1,
    xticks=[],
    yticks=[],
)

fig.get_axes()[-1].set_xlim(0, fig_width)
fig.get_axes()[-1].set_ylim(0, fig_height)

fig.add_axes(
    (0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4),
    alpha=1,
    xticks=[],
    yticks=[],
)

axis = fig.get_axes()[-1]

label = AnchoredText(
        s="Click here",
        frameon=False,
        loc="upper left",
        prop=dict(url="https://www.google.com"),
    )

axis.add_artist(label)

fig.savefig('diagram.svg')
```

In this case, let's say I want only the word "here" to be clickable out of the "Click here" AnchoredText.

I have looked at other, related, questions already but none address this specific problem. Perhaps there isn't a way to do this, I'm just not sure what other approach to take.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Sure, I added it just now.